# Swift Passing a member function to a function that takes an optional closure

Tags: swift, optional-parameters

I'm trying to construct a table that contains, among other things, an optional closure. When I try to instantiate an instance of the table, passing a member function for the closure I get a compile error.

From the error msg it appears that a member function can not be converted to an optional member function.  I don't see why not; an Int or other types can easily be converted to optionals.

```
struct Foo {

    typealias Routine = (_ x: Int) -> Int
    let int: Int
    let aRoutine: Routine?

    init(_ int: Int, _ routine: Routine? = nil) {
        self.int = int
        self.aRoutine = routine
    }
}

class Bar {

    let foo = Foo(5, doSomething) // Compile error here

    func doSomething(_ x: Int) -> Int {
        return x
    }
}
```

> Cannot convert value of type '(Bar) -> (Int) -> Int' to expected argument type 'Foo.Routine?' (aka 'Optional<(Int) -> Int>')

Answer (score 0):

You've just discovered that member functions (a.k.a. instance methods) are curried in Swift. See [Instance Methods are “Curried” Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)

`Foo.doSomething(_:)` isn't just a free function (a.k.a. global function). It's an instance method that has access to the instance, `self`. But if you just take the method as a closure directly, it doesn't know what the value of `self` would be.

There are several options:

1. If your implementation of `doSomething(_:)` doesn't need to access `self`, then you can move it out of the `Foo`'s declaration, and declare it as a global function.

   Alternatively, you can turn it into a static function by keeping it where it is and using the `static` modifier. This has an added benefit over a global function, in that it "organizes" your code by moving it into an appropriate namespace.
2. If your implementation of `doSomething(_:)` *does* need an instance to operate on, then you can access the unapplied method of that instance. Here's an example. I've added explicit type annotations for demonstration, but you should usually omit those.

   ```
   let object: Bar = Bar() // an object of type Bar

   let boundDoSomethingMethod: (Int) -> Int = object.doSomething // a bound method which operates on `object`

   // alternatively:
   let unboundDoSomethingMethod: (Bar) -> (Int) -> Int = Bar.doSomething
   let boundDoSomethingMethod: (Int) -> Int = unboundDoSomethingMethod(object)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I understand what's going on now - doSomething is ambiguous without an object.  I had declared it via let at class level.  Hence, it was set up before the Bar object was instantiated so there was no object.

I moved the let foo = Foo(5, doSomething) in the init routine of Bar and all is well.

Comment: @TroutStalker When you do that, you're implicitly refrencing `self.doSomething`, which is bound to `self`. Be careful with that, because if you store that `foo` within your `Bar` object, and your `foo` captures your `Bar` object, you end up with a strong reference cycle, and a memory leak

Comment: Again thanks.  I hadn't thought about the strong reference.  It shouldn't be a problem in this case since it's a command line app and both objects are in use throughout.  I'll keep it in mind for the future though.

Comment: @TroutStalker Eh, you never know when you accidentally copy paste some buggy code like that, and end up with a strong retain cycle where you don't want it. What are you trying to solve with `Foo`?